# How to make program return ID after the button will be pressed?

Tags: java, button, actionlistener

> This program return 0, need to stop/pause program, press button and then return ID.

```
static int ID=0;
static String log="";
static String pass="";
static SessionFactory factory;

public static int enterStudent(JPanel panel){

    panel.setLayout(null);
    JLabel jLabel=new JLabel("Login");
    panel.add(jLabel);
    jLabel.setBounds(10,10,100,30);
    JLabel jLabel1=new JLabel("Password");
    panel.add(jLabel1);
    jLabel1.setBounds(110,10,100,30);
    final JTextArea textArea=new JTextArea();
    textArea.setBounds(10,50,100,50);
    panel.add(textArea);
    final JTextArea textArea2=new JTextArea();
    textArea2.setBounds(110,50,100,50);
    panel.add(textArea2);
    JButton enterButton=new JButton("Enter");
    enterButton.setBounds(10,100,200,50);
    panel.add(enterButton);
    try {
        factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
```

> ActionListener

```
    enterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e2) {
            log=textArea.getText();
            pass=textArea2.getText();
            Session session = factory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = null;
            try{
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
                List students = session.createQuery("FROM Student").list();
                for (Iterator iterator =
                             students.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                    Student student = (Student) iterator.next();
                    if((student.getLogin().equals(log))&&(student.getPassword().equals(pass))){
                        ID=student.getId();//this should be returned
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"return="+ID);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                tx.commit();


            }catch (HibernateException e) {
                if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    });

    return ID; //returns 0
}
```

> This is function for LogIn, check login and pass in DATABASE. Need return ID of student, but program returns 0

Answer (score 0):

You can't return anything from an ActionListener since its method, `actionPerformed(...)` is defined to return `void`, nothing. But fortunately you don't need to. This is a Swing GUI, and inside of your  ActionListener, display the ID within a JLabel by calling `myLabel.setText(...)` or display it elsewhere where it needs to be displayed. Or if you don't want to display it, then call some class's `setId(...)` method.

Note that the true canonical answer to this question would be to use an M-V-C or Model-View-Control type design pattern, and in your ActionListener (part of the control), set the model's id field to the value found in the database. The GUI should have listeners attached to the model that would update the GUI's state (the data it displays) if the model's state changes. But for your simple program this would probably be a bit of over-kill.

Other side recommendations:

- Your code shows a significant over-use of static modifier, and doing this can make it hard to extend or enhance your program, or get it to easily work with other classes.
- Your code does not follow Java naming rules, and you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.
- While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

---

Edit: I now see that you're trying to return an int from the enterStudent method via the JButton's ActionListener. This won't work as written because you're returning the id field before the ActionListener has completed. Solutions include use a callback method of some sort, one that is perhaps passed into your enterStudent's method parameter, or else if you use a modal dialog such as is available with a JOptionPane. Otherwise, based on this increase in complexity, then yes, you're best off using an M-V-C structure which itself is based on use of listeners (callbacks).

Comment: Thanks for the idea "display the ID ".

Answer (score 0):

That means program control is not reaching this block hence your ID is getting the default defined value which is 0.

```
if((student.getLogin().equals(log))&&(student.getPassword().equals(pass))){
                        ID=student.getId();//this should be returned
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"return="+ID);
                        break;
                    }
```

here the if condition is not getting true which means either of getLogin() and getPassword is not having values as "".